Bamboo - The selenium driver server has unexpectedly died
New to the bamboo pipeline and upon running scripts the execution is failed with below error. Providing the config details for reference:
selenium-java - 4.18.1
selenium-chrome-driver - 4.18.1
chrome browser - 124.0.6367.60
This is the configuration updated for browser in the pipeline.
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Is there any way to choose my own browser version in the pipeline?
Which version is compatible(for driver and browser) to run the scripts in pipeline.
Note: The same config runs in my local.
Initially the scripts were failing even in the local, after updating the chrome driver versions all seems ok. But the pipeline results in failure.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The driver server has unexpectedly died! Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-1038-aws', java.version: '14.0.2' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Command: [622de560dac7508ec9879aa0660892f1, screenshot {}] Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome-headless-shell, browserVersion: 124.0.6367.60, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 124.0.6367.60 (8771130bd84f..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:35549}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:35549/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 124.0.6367.60, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true} Session ID: 622de560dac7508ec9879aa0660892f1

      org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The driver server has unexpectedly died!
Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-1038-aws', java.version: '14.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [622de560dac7508ec9879aa0660892f1, screenshot {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome-headless-shell, browserVersion: 124.0.6367.60, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 124.0.6367.60 (8771130bd84f..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:35549}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:35549/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 124.0.6367.60, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 622de560dac7508ec9879aa0660892f1
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:180)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:592)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:596)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
at utilities.UIAbstractTest.tearDown(UIAbstractTest.java:230)
at pns.features.userAuthentication.helpers.abstractTests.AbstractTest.tearDown(AbstractTest.java:38)
at pns.features.userAuthentication.LoginValidation.TearDown(LoginValidation.java:97)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:131)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.execute0(JdkHttpClient.java:443)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:55)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.execute(JdkHttpClient.java:359)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:589)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:839)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection$ConnectEvent.handle(PlainHttpConnection.java:128)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:968)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.lambda$run$3(HttpClientImpl.java:923)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:923)

